# Avoid type checking but preserve separation of concerns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, separation-of-concerns

I'm working on an MVVM project and trying to preserve separation of concerns.  Our current architecture has an entity framework model and MVVM light view and viewmodel projects.  I'm working ViewModel first so I'm passing those around with a datatemplate in the view project to get the proper view.

Having to type check every type to get the correct viewmodel just seems wrong. 
 Is there a better way?

To set this up suppose I have a model with classes:

```
namespace FoodData
{
    public class Hamburger:EntityObject
    {
            ..... //Add properties
    }

    public class Taco:EntityObject
    {
           .... //Add properties
    }

}
```

Now Lets say in my `ViewModel` namespace I have two different `ViewModels` for `Taco` and `Hamburger`

```
namespace FoodViewModel
{
  public class HamburgerViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
  }

  public class TacoViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
  }

  public class FoodViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {

    private ViewModelBase _displayViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase DisplayViewModel
    {
       get {return _displayViewModel;}
       set 
        {
            _displayViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayViewModel));
        }
     }

     private EntityObject _selectedFood;

     public EntityObject SelectedFood
     {
        get{return _selectedFood;}
        set
        {
          _selectedFood = value;
          DisplayViewModel = _selectedFood?.GetViewModel();
          RaisePoropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFood));
        }
     }

  }
}
```

The current solution I have is using extension methods in the `FoodViewModel` namespace

```
namespace FoodViewModel
{
   public static FoodViewModelExtensions
   {
       public static ViewModelBase GetViewModel(this EntityObject obj)
       {
            if(obj is Taco)
            {
              return new TacoViewModel();
            }
            if(obj is Hamburger)
            {
              return new HamburgerViewModel();
            }

            return new EmptyViewModel("Object not recognized");
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty obvious case for using an interface? Something like `IHasViewModel<out T> { T GetViewModel(); }`

Comment: So would the `IHasViewModel` be in the model's namespace?  Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Yes, then `class Taco : IHasViewModel<TacoViewModel> { ... }` etc.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid references to my `ViewModel` in my `Model`.  That is a solution but if I do it that way my `Model` would be dependent on my `ViewModel`.

Comment: If you want to avoid that you could create a visitor interface `IModelVisitor<TResult> { }` which your models implement to replace the dynamic type switching. Then create a `ViewModelVisitor : IModelVisitor<ViewModelBase>` to create the view models.

Comment: Ah OK, I will try that out.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary of model types -> view model types?

Comment: Yes, but that seems like the same thing different flavor.  I could add that somewhere but I will still need code to build the dictionary manually, which would require two places to edit when adding new types.

Comment: @JimmyJames I've been toying with the idea and I think yours may be the solution.  Using reflection I can build the dictionary at runtime.  I can just put constraints on the viewmodel abstract class requiring the target type.

Comment: @FelixCastor I consider it a configuration step.  I get that it feels unnecessary but I personally really like being able to look at some minimal code that explicitly sets things up instead of have to reason through some reflection magic and figure out why it's not working as I expect.  It might take a couple minutes to run after a new type is added and realize that I forgot to add it to the config versus hours trying to figure out why it's not being loaded automatically.  YMMV.

Comment: @JimmyJames I was worried about hiding behind reflection too but after working through your suggestion with reflection I was able to minimize its impact.  Now changes to the bottom level don't affect the top level.  And constraints are forced on new ViewModels using generics which will clear up confusion.  Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here between your models and viewmodels is a mapping.

No amount of code sorcery<sup>1</sup> is going to change the fact that you're going to have to map pairs of (model+viewmodel) in order to decide which viewmodel to use for your model. As this is a given, the only real discussion left is **how** we want to define this mapping.

There are myriad ways to do so; most of which can be argued pro and con. We've already seen a few in answers, which I'll include in the list. Others are my suggestions.

---

> - (suggested by Lee) Letting the model implement a generically typed interface for the viewmodel (`class Hamburger : IHasViewModel<HamburgerViewModel>`)

This is the first thing I thought of too. However, I do agree that it feels a bit dirty for your model to have to know its related viewmodel (especially if you have *several* viewmodels for a given model).

---

> - (suggested by Felix Castor) Setting a `Dictionary<ModelType,ViewModelType` defined by letting the viewmodel implement a generically typed interface for the model (`class HamburgerViewModel : FoodViewModelBase<Hamburger>`)

The interface implementation has the same pros and cons as the previous bullet point, but now you have an added responsibility of having to use reflection to compose a dictionary on the fly?

I'm not a fan of this added complexity. The previous bullet point seems objectively better (due to less management) with no additional drawbacks.

---

> - (as a counter to Felix Castor's idea): why not simply maintain the type dictionary yourself, and do away with the interfaces and reflection?

Something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<Type,Type> ModelToViewModelDict = new Dictionary<Type,Type>()
{
    { typeof(Hamburger) , typeof(HamburgerViewModel) }
    { typeof(Taco) , typeof(TacoViewModel) }
}
```

This way, neither your model nor viewmodel class definitions are dirtied, because the mapping is maintained externally to the classes.

Having to maintain the dictionary isn't really an issue (as discussed in the beginning, the mapping needs to be maintained *somewhere, in some shape* anyway).

---

> - Using a visitor.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the example, this would require a similar generically typed interface and, on top of that, also require you to design a visitor who needs to be updated for every newly added food.

I don't see the benefits of this approach compared to the others. You end up with the same "dirty" model/viewmodel link by implementing an interface from one one the other; while also having to maintain an extra definition.

However, I'll admit that I have little experience with the visitor pattern in general, so I may be unaware of additional pro's (or cons).

> **Edit**
>   The Visitor answer has been slightly updated since I wrote this, and I understand it a bit better now.
>   I still don't like it. It requires an overloaded method per entity type (which is very similar to your original `FoodViewModelExtensions` class); yet *also* requires every entity type to implement an interface (granted, it doesn't contain a generic type used for mapping purposes, but you are going to be copy/pasting **the same** interface method implementation all over your entities).
>
> This feel like double work. A mapping can be achieved with only doing one of the two tasks that the visitor requires.

---

> - Don't overgeneralize your method parameters.

If you need to know the *specific* type of your passed object, then don't declare it as a shared base type. Instead, rely on **overloading**:

```
public static ViewModelBase GetViewModel(this Taco obj)
{
    return new TacoViewModel(obj);
}

public static ViewModelBase GetViewModel(this Hamburger obj)
{
    return new HamburgerViewModel(obj);
}
```

This comes with the added benefit that you can choose whether a default option (when the type is not known) can be given, or instead throw a compile-time error. If you want no default option to exist, then keep the code as above. However, if you want to allow the passing of types that are not explicitly mapped, you can add a default:

```
public static ViewModelBase GetViewModel(this EntityObject obj)
{
    return new EmptyViewModel(obj);
}
```

> **Note for the default method**:
>   This is a bit of a pitfall. If you declare your entity as `EntityObject myTaco = new Taco();` and then call `GetViewModel(myTaco)`, you're going to end up in the default `GetViewModel(this EntityObject obj)` method; which is not what you'd want. This is because the *type of the variable* is used to decide which overloaded method to use.
>
> To avoid this, make sure you declare your entity by its proper type: `Taco myTaco = new Taco();` and then you will end up in the correct `GetViewModel(this Taco obj)` method.

Maintenance-wise, it's not all that different from your `if` chain. Originally, you needed to add a new `if` for every type, whereas now you need to add a new method for every type.

I like this version better, but I do concede that it at least *partially* relates to coding style preferences.

> **Note**
>   *Similar to how I advised against overgeneralizing your `Hamburger` and `Taco` objects as `EntityObject`s; there may be a similar argument to be made about having every method return a `ViewModelBase` as opposed to the specific `HamburgerViewModel` and `TacoViewModel`.*
>
> ***Even if** you handle the resulting viewmodel the same way, you can still have the method return an object of type `HamburgerViewModel` but choose to store the return object in a `ViewModelBase` variable (thus not changing anything). So I would suggest keeping the return type sufficiently specific, and not overgeneralized.*

---

> - Use a factory pattern.

This would be very similar to your current `FoodViewModelExtensions` class; with only a minor syntax change.

---

<sup>1</sup>I *really* wanted to come up with a suggestion that wouldn't require any manual maintenance when new entities get added to the codebase.

However, the best I could come up with is:

> - Using standardized naming across your model/viewmodel names, e.g. a `Foo` entity must have a viewmodel that is named `FooViewModel`.

You'll have to rely on reflection to find an object's corresponding viewmodel.Not having to manually maintain this is nice; but this is essentially a **[stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped)** approach; which I'm generally opposed to.

I'm *less* offended by the stringly typed approach than for other use cases; but it still feels a bit wrong to me. However, if you're **really** wanting to automate your mapping, this would effectively prevent you from having to manually maintain it.

---

**To conclude**

There are many ways to approach this. Each method has its own benefits, drawbacks, and applicability to the developer's preferred coding style (or the company's coding standards).

The most important thing to consider here is that you want your mapping to have a **minimal** footprint.

- At an absolute minimum, using naming conventions to auto-map models and viewmodels is viable; but comes with some drawbacks in that the structure of an application shouldn't be defined by the names that are used.
- A middle-of-the-road approach would require you to define the mapping *once*. There are two possibilities here:

  - Spreading the mapping over many locations (e.g. by having each model class definition list a `IHasViewModel<HamburgerViewModel>`)
  - Keeping the mapping contained in a single location (e.g. by using the dictionary, overloaded extension methods, or the factory). I much prefer this approach as it keeps the mapping centralized (inspired by SRP).
- What you should **definitely avoid** is having the mapping be defined more than once. The posted example of the visitor comes pretty close to this by having you maintain both an interface mapping and a visitor class definition, both of which need to be updated when a new entity is added into the mix.

In the end, it's really just dealer's choice. Company coding standards (or those of your team lead) will likely take precedence. If not available, then it's up to you to decide which approach's drawbacks you're most willing to live with.

Comment: "To avoid this, make sure you declare your entity by its proper type: `Taco myTaco = new Taco();`" is what got me down this rabbit hole in the first place.  Can't know before hand what concrete type of food needs to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You had me at "No amount of code sorcery1 is going to change the fact that you're going to have to map pairs of (model+viewmodel) in order to decide which viewmodel to use for your model"

Comment: @FelixCastor: That sounds more like you're dealing with overgeneralization of parameters in the calling code as well. When the object was initialized, you knew it was a `Taco`. But at this point, you seem to have lost that information and only know it's a `EntityObject`, which is the source of your issue. This is sort of why I advise against overgeneralization, you're now locked in an environment where it's impossible to know the original type, which is not a good approach.

Comment: @FelixCastor: As I mentioned in the answer, you should generally still be returning _specific_ types from methods, even if you end up assigning the return value to an `EntityObject` parameter. But if you downcast the variable to a `EntityObject`, and then realize that you need to know its specific type later on, _then you should not be downcasting the variable_. Either remove the downcasting (better option), or you'll be stuck with your `if(obj is Taco)` chain (not a good option).

Comment: @FelixCastor: `Can't know before hand what concrete type of food needs to be displayed.` Maybe not before compilation, but the application will know _at runtime_. In order to facilitate correct handling at runtime, you're going to have to implement a correct handling _for every possible type_. Whether you solve that through generics, method overloading, or _correct_ polymorphism is up to you; but given that you are trying to figure out the specific type of your base type object, that proves that your application's current polymorphism approach is not applied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to separating the declaration of a type hierarchy from the traversal is to use a visitor e.g.

```
public interface IModelVisitor<TResult>
{
    TResult Visit(Hamburger h);
    TResult Visit(Taco t);
}

public interface IModel
{
    TResult Accept<TResult>(IModelVisitor<TResult> visitor);
}

public class Taco : IModel
{
    TResult Accept<TResult>(IModelVisitor<TResult> visitor) 
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

then you can create a visitor for creating viewmodels:

```
public class ViewModelVisitor : IModelVisitor<ViewModelBase>
{
    public ViewModelBase Visit(Taco t) { return new TacoViewModel(); }
    public ViewModelBase Visit(Hamburger h) { return new HamburgerViewModel(); }
}
```

This approach requires to enumerate every model type in the visitor interface and add the `Accept` method to every model class. If you only have one visitor type this overhead may be unacceptable, and might prefer your existing approach, which you might be able to simplify with the pattern matching features in C#7.

Comment: Seems very similar to the extension methods.

Comment: @FelixCastor - It's similar but statically ensures you handle every model type defined in the `IModelVisitor<TResult>` interface. It also separates the type switching from the handler behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was in response to JimmyJames's comment.  I made a `Dictionary<Type, Type>` that mapped the two and used reflection to build the map at runtime.

I had to make an interface to get the types using reflection:

```
public interface IFoodViewModel
{
}
```

Then I included an abstract class that implemented the interface:

```
public abstract class FoodViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelBase, IFoodViewModel
   where T : EntityObject
{
}
```

Then the concrete ViewModel classes become

```
public HamburgerViewModel : FoodViewModelBase<Hamburger>
{
    // Add properties to bind to
}

public TacoViewModel : FoodViewModelBase<Taco>
{
    // Add properties to bind to
}
```

In my above example the `FoodViewModel` needs two more methods and a field added.

First add a dictionary to map them:

```
Dictionary<Type, Type> _viewModelMapping;
```

Second a method to build the map called from the constructor in FoodViewModel.

```
       private void BuildEditViewModelMap()
        {
            _viewModelMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => typeof(IfoodViewModel).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract && !p.IsInterface);
            foreach (var x in types)
            {
                if (x.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.Count() > 0)
                {
                    _viewModelMapping.Add(x.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0], x);
                }
            }
        }
```

And lastly a method to use the map to build ViewModels

```
private ViewModelBase GetViewModel(IDeviceModel device)
{
    // Note to add default arguments to create an instance add them to the object[] argument.
   var t = Activator.CreateInstance(_viewModelMapping[device.GetType()], new object[] {}) as ViewModelBase;
   return t;
}
```

**So in conclusion, what does this buy me?**

Now if I add a new food type say `Salad` to my model and need a new ViewModel to go with it, I just have to implement the abstract class FoodViewModelBase and FoodViewModel will handle the rest.  I'm happy with this solution.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

I might be wrong, but why not try a strcture of type `dynamic` and get rid of these hardcoded case switch variants..

Comment: How would this solve getting the correct viewmodel based on the model object?

Comment: You might  want to combine Visitor pattern fron above answer with dynamic typing @Felix

Comment: I would really like to keep strict typing in this project.  I prefer to provide abstractions that contain a family of strictly typed concrete classes versus dynamic typing.